# Why decomposition of gas on metal surface at high pressure considered 0 order

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, surface-chemistry, reaction-order

While reading my textbook it says that when ammonia decompose on a platinum surface at high pressure, the reaction is 0 order because at high pressure the metal surface get saturated with ammonia molecules and adding more ammonia will not change the rate of reaction. However, high pressure do not necessarily mean large number of molecules per unit volume instead temperature might be the reason for high pressure and molecules per unit volume remain same. If we do thought experiment with small number of molecules at high temperature colliding with metal surface then we can see there is still some space for additional molecules could take if added and the reaction will no longer be a 0 order despite the pressure is high. Is my textbook wrong?

Comment: your textbook is essentially correct. I guess your textbook relies on the fact that you are  working in conditions when you saturate the surface of the catalyst.  If the density of molecule is not enough to saturare the surface, of course you will not observe zero order kinetics. Somebody more familiar with the process could confirm this, but I guess your textbook is decribing the conditions that the catalyst is normally used and it is given you an example of a zero order process.

Comment: @PAEP but my book don't just simply said that at high pressure it would be 0 order reaction and reason they give is that at high pressure molecule concentration around platinum is high and it would saturated it's surface. But high temperature could also be the reason behind high pressure keeping the concentration of molecules same so in this condition how could metal surface get saturated

Comment: You seem confused. The point is that this reaction occurs on a 
*surface* not in a volume. it is easy to fill all the surface sites where the reaction can occur if the pressure is high enough. Hence there is no relationship with the bulk concentration. You can't force more molecules into the available reaction sites when they are already saturated.

Comment: @matt_black Saturation occur because molecules cover whole surface of metal at high pressure but suppose a metal can accomodate 10 molecules and we have only 5 molecules so still there is some space left on metal if we think all of them collide with metal at same time. So now if we increase pressure by increasing temperature then no matter how much pressure we apply the metal surface cannot be saturated and the statement that _decomposition of gas at metal surface at high pressure is 0 order reaction_ is not necessarily always valid.

Comment: @HarjotDhillon The *original* claim doesn't say the reaction will *always* be zero order. Your logic is correct. But the point of mentioning the *conditions* was to point out that the surface *would* be saturated. Under much lower pressure the reaction would not be zero order. The point is that, under conditions where the surface is saturated, the reaction **is** zero order.

Comment: Chemistry frequently uses simple models from boundary conditions. So look at it from the opposite point of view. "High pressure" means that the catalyst is saturated, and "low pressure" means that it is not. "High pressure" is easy to model since it is zero order. "Low pressure" on the other hand could be almost any order.

Comment: It is also generally assumed in catalytic reactions that the amount of catalyst is much less than the reactant

Answer (score 0):

Well textbook mostly tries to explain a concept in a broader and simple way rather than diving deep into different conditions in which reactions could occur (without giving much details of the conditions in which reaction is occurring). I don't know if our textbooks are same , but in the topic chemical kinetics this is mentioned as just an example of zero order reaction.
While studying such type of reactions in which information is incomplete, try to take that the other properties of system (which are not mentioned) at STP. This could help you to get the meaning of 'high pressure' given in the statement and in what context the example is trying to explain you zero order reactions.

I hope my answer helps